# Examples on Berkeley-db

Tags: c, berkeley-db

I need to create a simple database with just a primary key. I have been referring to "DB Reference Guide", but the examples over there are a bit confusing.

Are there any good materials especially focusing on examples to create Berkeley DB using C?

Comment: I am not sure if Berkley DB is the best solution.Sqllite should be simpler.

Comment: @doc_180: i have to do it in Bekeley DB    :(

Comment: I found that by following [this DB Reference Guide](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/documentation/BerkeleyDB/ref/toc.html) it was easy to create a database. What do you find confusing there?

Comment: @pmg: reading it....examples look more clear than the one that I had....thanks